# Spring mvc controller and composite primary keys

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity with a composite primary key, annotated with `@IdClass`. The class that represents the PK is serializable, and therefore I am able to create a JPA repository for the entity.

Now, I want to create a controller in which one of its actions is getting one entity by its ID. For other entities with simple PKs (i.e. an Integer), it is straightforward:

The controller/action is called with a Path variable: `myurl/controlles/action/1`

I get the `id` (1 in this case) variable and in the repository, I can call `findOne(id)`.

But with a composite PK, I guess I should specify somewhere how to serialize/deserialize it. For example, I would call `myurl/controllers/action/firstPKfield-secondPKfield` and then tell the controller somewhere that it should create a PK composite key from a string that has both fields separated by `-`.

Am I in a good direction?

Comment: why don't you create a class which has all the primary keys and accept it as an argument in your controller

Comment: But how can I receive it as a Path variable? (or a GET parameter)

Comment: you should accept it as a RequestBody and not as Path variable. It is not a good idea to accept as pathvariable when you have more variables. Your url will be too long in that case

Answer (score 1):

simply put your path value with whatever will be your character to separate your composite key.

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE;

@RestController
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping(value = "/poc/{firstKey}_{secondKey}", produces = TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    public String getResponse(@PathVariable String firstKey, @PathVariable String secondKey) {

        return String.format("firstKey = %s\nsecondKey = %s", firstKey, secondKey);
    }

}
```

Input

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/controller/poc/ABCDEF_123456
```

Output

```
firstKey = ABCDEF
secondKey = 123456
```